# Migrating records < 2millions using stored procedure (Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, data-migration

I have following Stored procedure. TempSourceTable has almost 0.7million records or may be 10millions. If the DestinationTable already contains the row then update DestinationTable row otherwise insert a new record in to DestinationTable

After executing the StoredProcedure there are no errors. But DestinationTable only has 10001 records only. What is wrong with following stored procedure.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Test] 
         @updatedCount int OUTPUT,
         @addedCount int OUTPUT
         AS
         BEGIN
           SET NOCOUNT ON;  
           DECLARE @updated int;
           DECLARE @added int;
           DECLARE @counter int;
           DECLARE @maxCount int;
           SET  @maxCount = (SELECT MAX(UniqueId) FROM #TempSourceTable);
           SET @counter = 1;
           SET @updated = 0;
           SET @added = 0;
           WHILE (@counter <= @maxCount)
             BEGIN
                Update DestinationTable
                    SET 
                        DestinationTable.Nome = #TempSourceTable.Nome,
                        DestinationTable.Cognome = #TempSourceTable.Cognome,
                        DestinationTable.CodiceFiscale = #TempSourceTable.CodiceFiscale,
                        DestinationTable.DataNascita = #TempSourceTable.DataNascita,
                        DestinationTable.Sesso = #TempSourceTable.Sesso,
                        DestinationTable.Email = #TempSourceTable.Email,
                        DestinationTable.Mobile = #TempSourceTable.Mobile,
                        DestinationTable.Telephone = #TempSourceTable.Telephone,
                        DestinationTable.Number = #TempSourceTable.Number,
                        DestinationTable.Street = #TempSourceTable.Street,
                        DestinationTable.City = #TempSourceTable.City,
                        DestinationTable.CAP = #TempSourceTable.CAP,
                        DestinationTable.Internal = #TempSourceTable.Internal,
                        DestinationTable.Province = #TempSourceTable.Province,
                        DestinationTable.USERID = #TempSourceTable.USERID
                    FROM  DestinationTable 
                    INNER JOIN #TempSourceTable  ON DestinationTable.CodiceFiscale = 
                       #TempSourceTable.CodiceFiscale
                        AND DestinationTable.CodiceCliente = #TempSourceTable.CodiceCliente
                    WHERE #TempSourceTable.UniqueId = @counter

            --SET @updated = @updated + 1;
            IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            BEGIN 
                --PRINT Concat('New insert with id: ', @counter)
                -- create a new patient
                INSERT INTO DestinationTable (Id, Nome, Cognome, CodiceFiscale, DataNascita, 
                            Sesso, Email, Mobile, Telephone, Number, Street, City, CAP, 
                Internal, Province, USERID,
                            DataInserimento, CodiceCliente)
                SELECT Id, Nome, Cognome, CodiceFiscale, DataNascita, 
                            Sesso, Email, Mobile, Telephone, Number, Street, City, CAP, 
                Internal, Province, USERID,
                            DataInserimento, CodiceCliente
                FROM #TempSourceTable
                WHERE UniqueId = @counter;

                SET @added = @added + 1;
            END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                 -- patient was found so update it by csv file data
                --PRINT Concat('FoundExistingPatient with id: ', @counter);
                SET @updated = @updated + 1;
                END 

         SET @counter = @counter + 1;
    END
    SET @addedCount = @added;
    SET @updatedCount = @updated;
    END
    GO
```

Comment: Ditch the `WHILE`, learn about `MERGE`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is very product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh I am using Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8

Comment: You don't need that join on the update, you can move the condition to the WHERE and achieve the same results.

Comment: @MikeMiller How then we can get the record of destination table to be updated and source table row ?

Comment: I just realized that above SQL table does correct job but  the TempSourceTable has duplicated records the unique rows are only 10001 so the SP only insert the unique rows and others are follows the update flow. This TempSourceTable is imported by CSV file which has 0.6millions records.  Anyway thank for everyone

Comment: Wow this row-by-agonising-row (RBAR) approach for 2 million records is a **really** bad idea. Please consider a set-based approach, either `MERGE` or separate `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, ideally within a transaction. Also, this proc won't work on ordinary Azure SQL DB, but it would work on Azure Synapse Analytics, dedicated SQL pool where you can create stored procs which use temp tables created in separate procs/code.  Are you sure you aren't using this row-based approach in Synapse in which case it would be even worse, and expensive!?  Your version number could be from the master database.

Comment: For huge list like 1million records it take atleast 30mins using the SQL Merge, For 100K records it take atleast 3.5mins. Is there anyway to reduce this time since it is really slow